# How to JSON.parse in html?

Tags: angular

I have this and i want to parse this params in html to get clean params but i dont know how.Any suggestion?

```
<a [routerLink]="[menu.url||'/']" [queryParams]="menu.refParameter3?JSON.parse(menu.refParameter3):{}"
```

Comment: i dont know why do i get -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

should better use a function inside your component, that will set your paramter
e.g.

```
routerJSON = {};

ngOnInit(){
   if( menu && menu.refParamter3 ) {
        this.routerJSON = JSON.parse(menu.refParameter3);
   }
}

<a [routerLink]="[menu.url||'/']" [queryParams]="routerJSON"></a>
```

alternative you can build/use a pipeline

```
[queryParams]="menu.refParameter3|json"
```